# Error when create Alfresco maven archetype on eclipse

Tags: java, maven, alfresco

[image]

I get error when create Alfresco maven archetype project on Eclipse

Comment: Could you please describe in more detail what you did?

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco comes with JRebel dependency by default. 
It is used for the hot-reloading purpose. But JRebel requires a license to
be installed. So you can simply remove/comment that  from pom.xml